# What is the proper way to verify an EmailMessage for proper recipient email addresses?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-email

I am developing an application with Django. In *forms.py*, where the classes for my forms are stored, I have written a clean function to verify that all the emails typed into a textbox adhere to the proper format (person@site.com).

In this clean function, I build the email message with an EmailMessage object:

```
def clean_recipients(self):
        rec = self.data['recipients'].split(",")
        recList = []
        for recipient in rec:
            reci = str.strip(str(recipient))
            recList.append(reci)
            message = (self.data['subject'], self.data['message'], 'hi@world.com', recList)
        mail = EmailMessage(self.data['subject'], self.data['message'], 'from@somebody.com', ['email_list@mysite.org'], recList)
        try:
            mail.send(fail_silently=False)
        except Exception:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please check inputted emails for validity.')
        return self.data['recipients']
```

However, the exception *'Please check inputted emails for validity.'* is never raised on the form regardless of what I input into the textbox. If I input random characters into the textbox, simply no message is sent.

What is the proper way to catch if the email was not sent properly?

Thank you.

Comment: You might find interesting information on http://www.rossp.org/blog/2010/jun/11/django-bounces-postmark/

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean recipients emails format only in the clean_recipients. There is snippet how to check email. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1093/ .  Raise validation error if email format does not match.

Create email and send it from the form's clean method (if you need show sending errors. You will need check for form errors before send.) or from the view.

PS. get your data this way - self.cleaned_data instead of self.data.